# Java: connect to hbase using rest client gives AuthenticationException

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, http-status-code-403

I am trying to connect hbase using **JAVA HBase Rest Client**. However it's giving following error.

The Hbase Rest uses kerberos authentication, and so I have created a kerberos ticket and trying to authenticate using this ticket.

**Code:**

```
public class RestExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
        conf.addResource("src/main/resources/hbase-site.xml");
        conf.addResource("src/main/resources/core-site.xml");
        conf.addResource("src/main/resources/hdfs-site.xml");

        System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf", "src/main/resources/krb5.conf");
        System.setProperty("sun.security.krb5.debug", "true");


        UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(conf);
        String projectDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        System.out.println(projectDir);
        UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab("gaurang.shah@mydomain.com", "src/main/resources/gaurang.shah.keytab");
        // vv RestExample
        Cluster cluster = new Cluster();
        cluster.add("hbase_host.mydomain.com", 17000); 

        Client client = new Client(cluster); 

        TableName tableName = TableName.valueOf("bda:aaa");

        RemoteAdmin remoteAdmin = new RemoteAdmin(client, conf);
        HTableDescriptor tableDesc = new HTableDescriptor(tableName);
        remoteAdmin.createTable(tableDesc);
    }
}
```

**Stacktrace:**

```
   Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed, URL: http://hbase_host.mydomain.com:17000/bda:aaa/schema?user.name=gaurang.shah, status: 403, message: Forbidden
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.rest.client.Client.negotiate(Client.java:285)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.rest.client.Client.executeURI(Client.java:239)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.rest.client.Client.executePathOnly(Client.java:204)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.rest.client.Client.execute(Client.java:265)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.rest.client.Client.put(Client.java:557)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.rest.client.Client.put(Client.java:504)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.rest.client.Client.put(Client.java:474)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.rest.client.RemoteAdmin.createTable(RemoteAdmin.java:294)
    at ca.cantire.RestExample.main(RestExample.java:42)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed, URL: http://hbase_host.mydomain.com:17000/bda:aaa/schema?user.name=gaurang.shah, status: 403, message: Forbidden
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.AuthenticatedURL.extractToken(AuthenticatedURL.java:281)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.PseudoAuthenticator.authenticate(PseudoAuthenticator.java:77)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.KerberosAuthenticator.authenticate(KerberosAuthenticator.java:212)


  at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.rest.client.Client.negotiate(Client.java:280)
    ... 8 more
```

Comment: where is stacktrack ?

Comment: @ShivaKumarSS sorry, it was typo mistake.

Comment: Try adding these resources by giving absolute path.  eg  

        conf.addResource("file://{absolutepath}");

Comment: @ShivaKumarSS same error.